# issue with if/else and switch statements

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

the following code is to handle ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP events for a button named clash.  the idea is that once if/else determines that the onTouch event was caused by clash and the switch statement then determines what to do based on the action.  i don't know if the problem is that the switch statements are not returning true and that may be related to the problem. when i add a return, eclipse says that the code is unreachable which i don't understand.  i was under the impression that you can't break out of a switch without break.

what's actually happening is that the first sound will loop but the code never seems to detect the action up when the button is released and so the sound plays forever.  any help would be appreciated.

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.clash);
 if (v.getId() == R.id.clash){

 switch (event.getAction()){

 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
  mp.setLooping(true);
  mp.start();
   break;

 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  mp.pause();
  break;
 }

}
return true;
}
   });
```

Comment: even after adding "return true;" i'm still not getting anything on action up.  i can even put the code to play the sound in that case rather than action down and it does nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure on this, but wouldn't this be creating a new MediaPlayer object each time you press OR release? In which case, you would be calling `pause()` on a different MediaPlayer instance than `start()` was called on?

Comment: that does make sense.  the problem is, when i move the creation of mp to the part of the logic that handles the ACTION_DOWN event, nothing happens.  it doesn't play any sounds at all.  i'm starting to consider giving up on MediaPlayer completely since i have to create and destroy the object every time a sound is played.  Every search i do states that you can't setDataSource on the fly.

Comment: after closer examination, i've found that with the mp object being created in the if/else statement, logcat doesn't even see when the button is clicked.  it's as if the entire listener is broken.

Comment: Hmm. That is strange. If the sound plays with the MediaPlayer outside the switch statement, then it has to be reaching the ACTION_DOWN case. I'm going to post some thoughts in a post below - I don't have a way to test this right now, so some syntax may be off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Add the following line in the code before your setOnTouchListener()
MediaPlayer mp;

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 

    if (v.getId() == R.id.clash){ 

        switch (event.getAction()) { 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.clash); 
            mp.setLooping(true); 
            mp.start(); 
            break; 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            if(mp != null) 
            {
                mp.pause(); 
                mp.release();
            }
            break; 
        } 
    } 
} 

// I'm assuming this was from the onTouchListener()? -> });
```

Just a thought.

Comment: that works out just fine.  thanks a lot, man.  it was a basic problem but i couldn't for the life of me get it right.